# Urls NoReverseMatch : no pattern tried

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to return a url at the end of my method :

```
return reverse('list-remote-networks', kwargs={'datacenter_id': datacenter_id})`
```

In my urls.py this the lines assiciate with this urls :

```
DATACENTER = r'^(?P<datacenter_id>[^/]+)/%s$'
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(DATACENTER % 'list-remote-networks', views.NetworkView.as_view(), name='list-remote-networks'),
```

Do I miss something? My others urls works well.
Edit : this is the urls.py file.

```
`DATACENTER = r'^(?P<datacenter_id>[^/]+)/%s$'
NETWORK = r'^(?P<remote_network_id>[^/]+)/%s$'
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(DATACENTER % 'remotelogin', views.remotelogin, name='remotelogin'),
    url(DATACENTER % 'list-remote-networks', views.NetworkView.as_view(), name='list-remote-networks'),
    url(r'^(?P<datacenter_id>[^/]+)/(?P<remote_tenant_id>[^/]+)/(?P<remote_network_id>[^/]+)/%s$' % 'connectnetworks', views.ConnectNetworkView.as_view(), name='connectnetworks'),

 )`
```

Comment: What is the value of the `datacenter_id`?

Comment: datacenter_id is a string

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can test your regexes:

```
>>> import re
>>> match_string = re.match(r'^(?P<datacenter_id>[^/]+)/%s$' % 'list-remote-networks', 'abc/list-remote-networks')
>>> match_string.groupdict()
{'datacenter_id': 'abc'}
>>> match_nums = re.match(r'^(?P<datacenter_id>[^/]+)/%s$' % 'list-remote-networks', '123/list-remote-networks')
>>> match_nums.groupdict()
{'datacenter_id': '123'}
>>> match_special_chars = re.match(r'^(?P<datacenter_id>[^/]+)/%s$' % 'list-remote-networks', '123-abc?_+@#/list-remote-networks')
>>> match_special_chars.groupdict()
{'datacenter_id': '123-abc?_+@#'}
```

I don't think the issue here is your regex.  My suspicion is that one of the following things has happened:

1. You added this to your urls.py file without reloading Django; Django didn't pick it up. Killing and restarting Django is the easy way to check on this.
2. This file isn't being loaded like you think it is by the parent urls.py file. I'm assuming this is not a root path because you're leading with an id. The include entry for this urls file may be missing, or there might be a namespace that's not being referenced properly.  If you DID use a namespace, the reverse would look like this:

`reverse('namespace-name:list-remote-networks', kwargs={'datacenter_id': datacenter_id})`

Comment: 1. Yes I reload Django after each modification.    
2. I'm sure too. I have tried with just this and it's the same:    
return reverse('list-remote-networks')    
and    
url('list-remote-networks', views.NetworkView.as_view(), name='list-remote-networks')

Comment: Are any of the other views in that particular file being looked up properly?

Comment: Yes, the others works well. It's why it's very strange.

Comment: Entire urls.py file added to initial question. With  return reverse('remote_data_centers:list-remote-networks', kwargs={'datacenter_id': datacenter_id}) I have the error "remote_data_centers' is not a registered namespace" :(

Comment: OK. Maybe I have found the begining of the solution. With the complete namespace `return reverse('horizon:project:remote_data_centers:list-remote-networks', kwargs={'datacenter_id': datacenter_id})` I have now the error `Exception Value: 
'str' object has no attribute 'get'` but I don't see why.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('horizon:project:remote_data_centers:list-remote-networks',
                                            kwargs={'datacenter_id': datacenter_id}))
```

But now I have a other problem. Just before the return instruction, I save a variable in a session :

```
request.session['remote_dc_id'] = datacenter_id
```

After my redirection, in my views.NetworkView.as_view() I'm trying to get my value save just before :

```
class NetworkView(tables.DataTableView):  
table_class = NetworksDCTable  
template_name = 'project/remote_data_centers/networks.html'  
def get_data(self):  
    remote_dc_id = self.request.session['remote_dc_id']
```

But I can't get my value. This error is returned :

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'remote_dc_id'
```